# How to execute Stored Procedure in ASP.NET for SelectedIndex Values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I'm new to ASP.NET, googled every single form but can't found a better solution. I'm executing  a procedure using following code, but no success:

I need to provide Month and Year Values not SelectedIndex to the Stored Procedure.

Thanx in Advance.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var months = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.MonthNames;
    slMonth.DataSource = months;
    slMonth.DataBind();

    ListItem li = new ListItem();
    li.Text = "-Select Month-";
    li.Value = "-1";
    slMonth.Items.Insert(0, li);
    slMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;

    slYear.Items.Insert(0, "-Select Year-");
    int index = 1;
    for (int Year = 2000; Year <= DateTime.Now.Year; Year++)
    {
        ListItem liYear = new ListItem(Year.ToString(), Year.ToString());
        slYear.Items.Insert(index, liYear);
        index++;

    }
}
protected void Update_Spend(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=RFMMailServ;Database=Acquiring;User Id=sa;Password=+RFM@Pr0300k+;");
    SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("UpdatetblRPT_Spend", SQLConn);
    cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = slMonth.SelectedIndex;
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = slYear.SelectedIndex;
    SQLConn.Open();
    cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
    LastMsg.Text = "Spend updated successfully.";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _no success_ ? You get any exception or error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure out the problem, see the code below, now there is one thing, that on localhost the Year Combo is displaying the list for Single time, but when I execute the solution on client machine, the Year Combo display the values twice?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.slMonth.Items.Count <= 0)
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            slMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(
                System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i),
                i.ToString()
            ));
        }

    ListItem li = new ListItem();
    li.Text = "-Select Month-";
    li.Value = "0";
    slMonth.Items.Insert(0, li);


    slYear.Items.Insert(0, "-Select Year-");
    int index = 1;
    for (int Year = 2000; Year <= DateTime.Now.Year; Year++)
    {
        ListItem liYear = new ListItem(Year.ToString(), Year.ToString());
        slYear.Items.Insert(index, liYear);
        index++;

    }
}
protected void Update_Spend(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection SQLConn = null;
    try
    {
        SQLConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=./;Database=ACQ;User Id=sa;Password=PWD;");
        SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand();
        cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UpdatetblRPT_Spend";
        cmdUpdate.Connection = SQLConn;
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = slMonth.SelectedValue;
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = slYear.SelectedValue;
        SQLConn.Open();
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        LastMsg.Text = "Spend updated successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        SQLConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [selectedvalue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not selectedindex

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the listbox index, not the value. Also, you are assigning int Year to a varchar type Db column. Please make sure to mention what errors/output you've got while executing your code. It'll save us some time.

Try this instead:

```
protected void Update_Spend(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=RFMMailServ;Database=Acquiring;User Id=sa;Password=+RFM@Pr0300k+;");
  SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("UpdatetblRPT_Spend", SQLConn);
  cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(slMonth.SelectedValue);
  cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = slYear.SelectedValue;
  SQLConn.Open();
  cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
  LastMsg.Text = "Spend updated successfully.";
```

}

Comment: There is no error, but the procedure is not updating the data. I've double checked by executing the procedure through SQL Prompt, and its working fine.

Comment: Have you tried the corrected method posted above? Please add your Stored Procedure and the query which you executed via SQL prompt. It'll help us identify the issue. please throw the exception in the catch box by adding throw; You are just capturing error and avoiding it, That's why there is no error shown.